# Is this binding breaking?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

If I a dp a and a dp b, if i bind b to a, say a is 100, b becomes 100, if later assign b to 80 would that break the binding? so if I later assign a t0 70 b will not get updated? maybe a better approach would be to change b in a's on value changed method, then the following example would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to (temporarily, until next change of `a`) set the value of `b` to 70 without breaking the binding, you can call [`SetCurrentValue(bProperty, 70)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) on the DependencyObject that defines DependencyProperty `b`. This works as long as the dependency property is backed by a public static field as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist) (which is afaik true for the dependency properties of all WPF components).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will break the binding because you are replacing the bound value with a static value.

To maintain the binding when updating B, you'll need to get the binding on property B and update it's Source. This means you would actually be updating property A.

Comment: so it is like using a two way binding mode.